# Need help in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Iam very new in stored procedure, No need to check query working but any better code will be highly appreciable.
I have Two tables
1.Users===>The main records table 
2.temp_Users===> Table contain updated current users information
My required task is
A.Check user that need to be deleted.
B.Add new users that are not in Table **Users** from Table **temp_Users**

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE checkUsers()
      BEGIN
      DECLARE oldusers, newusers INT DEFAULT 0

//To catch delete users      
      SELECT COUNT(Users.Ext) INTO oldusers
      FROM Users
      LEFT JOIN temp_Users
      ON temp_Users.Ext=Users.Ext
      WHERE temp_Users.Ext IS NULL;

//To catch new users    
      SELECT COUNT(temp_Users.Ext) INTO newusers
      FROM Users
      RIGHT JOIN temp_Users
      ON temp_Users.Ext=Users.Ext
      WHERE Users.Ext IS NULL;

      CASE 
         WHEN oldusers>0
         THEN DELETE FROM Users SELECT Users.Ext
              FROM Users
              LEFT JOIN temp_Users
              ON temp_Users.Ext=Users.Ext
              WHERE temp_Users.Ext IS NULL;

         WHEN newusers>0
         THEN INSERT INTO Users (Ext) SELECT temp_Users.Ext
              FROM Users
              RIGHT JOIN temp_Users
              ON temp_Users.Ext=Users.Ext
              WHERE Users.Ext IS NULL;
         ELSE exit;
         END CASE;


      END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You can remove both of your initial `SELECT` statements, as well as the assignment to `oldusers` and `newusers`, and remove the `CASE` as well. Just run your `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements; if there are rows that match the criteria, the action will take place, and if there aren't any it won't. You don't need the `COUNT` or variables.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes this will be my last option but need to learn how it will works with this.

Comment: You want to learn how to write code you don't need? I'm afraid that makes no sense - you asked for better code, and I told you what you needed for better code (get rid of the unnecessary stuff). :)

Comment: @KenWhite could you please tell my why my following query is not working ?
DELETE FROM Users 
SELECT Users.Ext
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN temp_Users
ON temp_Users.Ext=Users.Ext
WHERE temp_Users.Ext IS NULL

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. (**UNTESTED** - I'm not a MySQL user, so you'll want to test this carefully first!) `DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.Ext IN (SELECT Users.Ext FROM Users u LEFT JOIN temp_Users t on t.Ext = u.Ext WHERE t.Ext IS NULL)` should work. (BTW, this should have been a separate question. :) )

Answer (score 0):

Your delete query should be -

```
DELETE Users
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN temp_Users
    ON temp_Users.Ext=Users.Ext
WHERE temp_Users.Ext IS NULL;
```